# How to access a class member through a variable

Tags: c#, methods, types

I have a class that I've created

```
public class DataRecord
{
     public string PayerAccount { get; set; }
     public string GlobalEntityType { get; set; }
     public string GlobalEntityNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

I am now trying to access this DataRecord in a different method through the use of a variable

```
public List<DataTest> CountAndFrequency(IEnumerable records, string ColumnName, int numResults)
{
     foreach (DataRecord record in records)
     {
           record.ColumnName = record.ColumnName.ToUpper();
     }
}
```

I am getting the error that DataRecord does not contain a definition for ColumnName, which of course makes sense. The question is, how do I combat this issue? I've been scouring the internet to no avail and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue you want to combat?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `IEnumerable<DataRecord>`?

Comment: You want to look at ExpandoObject if you are interested in creating properties on the go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection for this. Try this

```
    public static List<DataTest> CountAndFrequency(IEnumerable<DataRecord> records, string ColumnName, int numResults)
    {
        foreach (DataRecord record in records)
        {
            var prop = typeof(DataRecord).GetProperty(ColumnName);
            var value = prop.GetValue(record).ToString().ToUpper();
            prop.SetValue(record, value);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access data via a string name, you store the data in a `Dictionary<string,string>`.

```
public class DataRecord
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> data;

    public DataRecord()
    {
        this.data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    // Access data with names
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get{ return data[columnName]; } 
        set{ data[columnName] = value;}
    }
    // Fake properties
    public string PayerAccount
    {
        get => data[nameof(PayerAccount)];
        set => data[nameof(PayerAccount)] = value;
    }
    public string GlobalEntityType
    {
        get => data[nameof(GlobalEntityType)];
        set => data[nameof(GlobalEntityType)] = value;
    }
    public string GlobalEntityNumber
    {
        get => data[nameof(GlobalEntityNumber)];
        set => data[nameof(GlobalEntityNumber)] = value;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var record = new DataRecord
        {
            PayerAccount = "10024",
            GlobalEntityType = "QXT",
            GlobalEntityNumber = "509382"
        };

        var number = record["GlobalEntityNumber"];
        // 509382
    }
}
```